# Can we configure Vim tag following to be more intelligent?

Tags: tags

In large code bases, there can be multiple hits for an identifier. Sometimes dozens. When you look up a tag, the first choice in the list is often some false positive you don't want.

The user experience for finding the right tag is quite poor; you have to scroll through some list (in one direction only) where the location you want might be #37 or whatever.

Then, if you chase that same tag again, it appears in the same #37 position in the same list.

Is there a way to:

- have recent matches go to the top of the list? So if you jump to the same definition twice, the second time it should be in the #1 position? (Such that the recently-used info is saved in Vim sessions, ideally.)
- prioritize the matches by whether those files are currently open in a buffer? E.g. suppose there are 117 matches for a tag, but three of them land in files that are currently open in buffers: those three should be at the top. (And perhaps if exactly one match occurs in a buffered file, it should just bypass the list and jump to that one.)

Answer (score 1):

> prioritize the matches by whether those files are currently open in a buffer

This should be doable by setting [tagfunc](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27tagfunc%27). call [taglist](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#taglist%28%29)() and sort based on if files are open.

Comment: That seems very promising. In fact this `tagfunc` completely abstracts the search. I will look into what it would take for it to keep a recent list, in such a way that the list will persist with Vim sessions too.

Comment: Alas, `tagfunc` appears not to be implemented yet in Vim 8, which is what you get on Ubuntu 18, which I'm still using.

Comment: You can install a newer Vim.

Comment: ... or a newer Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

The [`:ltag`](https://vimhelp.org/tagsrch.txt.html#%3Altag) command populates the location list with the list of matching tags.  This makes it easier to browse the list.

Note: The location list feature was originally added to Vim to support this command.

Comment: Any way to get it into quickfix list instead?

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you some Fuzzy plugins like:

- [Fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim)
- [CtrlP](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim)
- [vim-clap](https://github.com/liuchengxu/vim-clap)
- [Telescope](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim) (for Neovim only)

They have provider from tags that can be filtered using fuzzy logic.

In Fzf you can:

- Use the `:Tags` command to list the project tags and fuzzy search them.
- Use the `:BTags` command to list the buffer tags and fuzzy search them.

In CtrlP you can:

- Use the `:CtrlPTag` command to list the project tags and fuzzy search them.
- Use the `:CtrlPBufTagAll` command to list the **buffers** tags and fuzzy search them.

In vim-clap you can:

- Use the `:Clap proj_tags` command to list the project tags and fuzzy search them.

[image]

In Telescope you can:

- Use the `:Telescope tags` command to list the project tags and fuzzy search them.
- Use the `:Telescope current_buffer_tags` command to list the buffer tags and fuzzy search them.

This is not fully answer your question but maybe an extended version of the Fzf or vim-clap provider would be the way to go to fulfill your demands.